# in iOS Storyboard horizontal StackView center align elements and impose height of first element on all elements

Tags: ios, storyboard, uistoryboard, xcode-storyboard

In my storyboard file, I have a horizontal StackView which is center aligned (both horizontally and vertically) in parent view.
This stack contains three element

1. Label "Hi"
2. Image (an image from resource folder)
3. Label "World"

StackView configuraation:

Distribution = Fill

Alignment = Last Baseline

In storyboard all items looks of the same height,
but when ran on device, two label stays same size but image vertically resizes, and height start to mismatch with two label.

How can I impose height restriction on image, to match with label heights?

Note I have not specified a fixed height for any of my elements.

Comment: Have you applied any constraints to this stack view? Provide some screenshots of your story board & what is appearing in device or simulator after running the app.

Comment: It's not clear what you want or what you are getting. Add a couple images to your question, showing your desired result vs your current result.

Answer (score 1):

I want you to make some changes:

1. Distribution = **Fill Equally**
2. Give equal height constraint to image, both labels.
3. You can set **content mode for image to Scale to Fill** to make image cover whole area.
   [image]
4. You are Done.

**Result: See below Image**
[image]

Comment: Hello Sir if this answer is correct, please mark it done.